# Mobile platform with public Bluetooth API?

Tags: mobile, bluetooth, communication

We will have a project where we need Bluetooth communication. Thus I'm trying to collect all the possible list of latest phone which has public bluetooth API. So far I found the following phones:-

1. Android
2. Meego/Maemo
3. J2me

I would like to know are there any other phones We could consider for Bluetooth communication. Please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use iphone with iOS 5, as Bluetooth APIs are now exposed

Comment: iOS always also supported Bluetooth iOS 4 also has Bluetooth supported

Comment: Older iOS gives very limited access to what you can do with BT unless you were enrolled in MFi

Comment: yes you are correct - iOS bluetooth needs MFi the new addition is Bluetooth Low Energy (Bluetooth Smart Ready) which iOS5 now adds (I thought the question was more on regular Bluetooth)

Answer (score 0):

Almost all smartphones (iOS, Android, Blackberry, J2MS, Windows Phone etc) have bluetooth APIs.
Not all are similar - very one is different and have different level of capability and issues in some.
Depending on your application and use case you need to decide.